# How can I use Godot 4.0 C# with dotnet run watch?

Tags: c#, godot, dotnet-cli

Godot 4.0 beta has shipped with C# support, and it reportedly works out of the box with hot-reload support in Visual Studio.

I would like to get this working on my Mac, which doesn't have Visual Studio. I took the `launchSettings.json` and put it in my Godot project in "Properties/launchSettings.json" with this content (taken from what Visual Studio autogenerated):

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "/path/to/Godot_csharp_b1.app/Contents/MacOS/Godot",
      "commandLineArgs": "--debug-server tcp://127.0.0.1:6666",
      "workingDirectory": "/path/to/my/project",
      "authenticationMode": "None",
      "remoteDebugEnabled": false,
      "remoteDebugMachine": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Now I try to do this:

```
dotnet watch run --launch-profile Development
```

However, it doesn't work. It gives this error:

```
The launch profile "Development" could not be applied.
The launch profile type 'Executable' is not supported.
Unable to run your project.
Ensure you have a runnable project type and ensure 'dotnet run' supports this project.
A runnable project should target a runnable TFM (for instance, net5.0) and have OutputType 'Exe'.
The current OutputType is 'Library'.
```

Is it possible to work around this? Any way to run Godot on MacOS with hot reloading would be acceptable for me - command line or anything else.

I'm on MacOS + M1 if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My original answer misunderstood the question, but I will leave it below as it may be helpful.

Regarding hot reloading, I am not sure Godot 4 is capable of playing nicely with `dotnet watch` as I haven't been able to find much on it. However, I was able to find this [outstanding issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/67719) regarding hot reload in Godot 4 beta 3, but that's about it. It will likely be some time before Godot 4 reaches stable, so this may change rapidly over the coming weeks.

---

If you are trying to debug a Godot 4 C# project with Visual Studio Code, you can do so with the following `launch.json` configuration. Note that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two entirely different IDE's. Just place the snippet below in a file at `.vscode/launch.json` in your Godot project:

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    // For these launch configurations to work, you need to setup a GODOT4
    // environment variable. On mac or linux, this can be done by adding
    // the following to your .zshrc, .bashrc, or .bash_profile file:
    // export GODOT4="/Applications/Godot.app/Contents/MacOS/Godot"
    {
      "name": "Play",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "${env:GODOT4}",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
    },
  }
}
```

Make sure you have a `GODOT4` environment variable that points to your Godot4 executable.

You will also need to place the snippet below in your `.vscode/tasks.json` file, since the launch configuration above depends on it to make sure that `dotnet build` is run before debugging.

```js
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "build"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "silent",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you are looking for Godot 3 `launch.json` configurations, [you can find those here](https://github.com/chickensoft-games/go_dot_test#godot-3x-launch-configurations).

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't appear to address the `watch` bit of the question, which is the bit I was most interested in.

Comment: @thedayturns Sorry, I misread part of the question. I didn't realize .NET 6 included hot reloading out of the box until now, and even then, I'm not sure Godot is designed to support it. I found this issue https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/67719, but no additional context. If you have more, please consider linking it so I can take a look.

Comment: No worries! There were reports from the community on Discord that dotnet watch was working with Godot on Windows machines. Unfortunately, we have (so far) been unable to get it to work on Mac.